# Spring KafkaListener not picking earliest uncommitted offset after pause resume

Tags: spring, spring-kafka, resume, pause

UseCase - Looking to pause a Spring KafkaListener for few seconds in case of Retryable Exceptions coming from an external service and want to resume from the earliest uncommitted offset.

Problem I have - Below is the implementation.

1) With out Seek usage - After resume spring kafkalistener is picking the latest message coming into the topic partition. This is defeating the purpose (messages between last committed offset to the latest offset are missing)

2) With seek usage - I don't know how to get a handle of kafkaconsumer

SOURCE CODE

> Lisener Method in a Consumer

```
 @KafkaListener(topics = "${kafka.consumer.topic}", containerFactory = "kafkaListenerContainerFactory")
    public void onReceiving(@Payload ConsumerRecord<String, String> consumerRecord, Acknowledgment acknowledgment) {

            try {
                Event event = translate(consumerRecord);
                someService.processEvent(event, consumerRecord);
                commitOffset(acknowledgment)
            } catch(ConsumerException e) {
                //DO NOT commit offset
            }
        }

    private void commitOffset(Acknowledgment acknowledgment) {
        acknowledgment.acknowledge();
    }
```

> ```
> Service
> ```

```
public void processEvent(Event event, ConsumerRecord<String, String> consumerRecord) {

    try {
        //call an external API to get realTime event details
        //Have a retry on this client
       BusinessEntity businessEntity = externalServiceClient.get(event);
       //process the Entity 
       anotherService.process(businessEntity);
    } catch(RetryableException re) {
        //feign.RetryableException
        //we are using feign declarative clients 
        consumerErrorHandler.handle(re, consumerRecord);
    }
}
```

> ErrorHandler --> implements 
>   org.springframework.kafka.listener.ErrorHandler

```
public class ConsumerErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {

    @Autowired
    private final KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry registry;

    //org.springframework.core.task.SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor
    @Autowrired 
    private final Executor executor;

    @Autowired
    private Consumer<String, String> kafkaConsumer;

    @Override
    public void handle(Exception thrownException, ConsumerRecord<?, ?> data) {

        //Trying to delegate this to a new Async thread.

        executor.execute(() -> {
            registry.getListenerContainers().forEach(container -> {

                if ((!container.isContainerPaused() || !container.isPauseRequested())) {
                    log.info("STOPPING_CONSUMER on error");

                    Optional<TopicPartition> topicPartition = container.getAssignedPartitions().stream().filter(a -> a.partition() == data.partition()).findFirst();

                    container.pause();
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(5000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                    }

                    log.info("BEFORE_RESUME");
                    log.info("SEEK CONSUMER before RESUME to this offset: "+data.offset());

                    topicPartition.ifPresent(a ->
                    {
                        log.info("Seek from the current position: " + data.offset());
                        kafkaConsumer.seek(a, data.offset());
                    });

                    container.resume();

                    log.info("RESUMING_CONSUMER  after seek");

                    topicPartition.ifPresent(a -> {
                        log.info("CONSUMER is up NOW ??");
                    });
                }
            });
        });

    }
}
```

> Consumer Configurations

```
    private Map<String, Object> consumerConfigs() {
        Map<String, Object> confMap = new HashMap<>();
        confMap.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, pubSubServers);
        confMap.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        confMap.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        confMap.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, consumerGroupIdConfig);
        confMap.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, "50000");
        confMap.put(ConsumerConfig.SESSION_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, "50000");
        confMap.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, false);
        confMap.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, OffsetResetStrategy.EARLIEST.name().toLowerCase());
        if (this.securityProtocol.equalsIgnoreCase(SSL)) {
            confMap.put(CommonClientConfigs.SECURITY_PROTOCOL_CONFIG, this.securityProtocol);
            confMap.put(SslConfigs.SSL_TRUSTSTORE_LOCATION_CONFIG,
                    this.getClass().getResource(clientTrustStoreLocation).getPath());
            confMap.put(SslConfigs.SSL_TRUSTSTORE_PASSWORD_CONFIG, this.sslTrustStorePassword);
            confMap.put(SslConfigs.SSL_KEYSTORE_LOCATION_CONFIG,
                    this.getClass().getResource(this.clientKeyStoreLocation).getPath());
            confMap.put(SslConfigs.SSL_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD_CONFIG, sslKeyStorePassword);
            confMap.put(SslConfigs.SSL_KEY_PASSWORD_CONFIG, sslKeyPassword);
            confMap.put(SslConfigs.SSL_ENDPOINT_IDENTIFICATION_ALGORITHM_CONFIG,null);
        }
        return confMap;
    }

    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory() {
      return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerConfigs());
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaListenerContainerFactory<ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, String>> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
      ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory =
          new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
      factory.setConcurrency("1");
      factory.getContainerProperties().setAckOnError(false);
      factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(AckMode.MANUAL_IMMEDIATE);
      factory.getContainerProperties().setConsumerTaskExecutor(taskExecutor());
      factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
      factory.setErrorHandler(consumerErrorHandler);
      factory.setRetryTemplate(retryTemplate());
      return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public AsyncListenableTaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
      return createTaskExecutor("1");
    }

     private RetryTemplate retryTemplate() {
         RetryTemplate template = new RetryTemplate();
         template.setRetryPolicy(retryPolicy());
         template.setBackOffPolicy(backOffPolicy());
         return template;
    }

    private BackOffPolicy backOffPolicy() {
        ExponentialBackOffPolicy policy = new ExponentialBackOffPolicy();
        policy.setInitialInterval(1000);
        return policy;
    }

    private RetryPolicy retryPolicy() {
         SimpleRetryPolicy policy = new SimpleRetryPolicy();
         policy.setMaxAttempts("1");
         return policy;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `ConsumerAwareErrorHandler`.

You **cannot perform the seek on another thread**. See the `KafkaConsumer` javadocs - it is not thread-safe.

You also must seek any remaining records for other topics/partitions (unless you only have one topic/partition).

Finally, you must not exit the error handler until the container is paused - otherwise there will be a race and the consumer might do another `poll()` before it `pause()`es.

See the `SeekToCurrentErrorHandler` and `ContainerStoppingErrorHandler` for examples of how to do this kind of thing. `stop()` has to be called on another thread to avoid a deadlock, but you can `pause()` the container on the consumer thread (it just sets a flag so the consumer will `pause()` before the next `poll()`.

To `resume()` the container, use an `ApplicationListener` or `@EventListener` to listen for container idle events for the paused container (set the `idleEventIterval` to get those events.